# Why is my query failing? Trying to apply sort order on GAE datastore entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

```
    q = Institution_Table.all().run(batch_size=2000).order('name')
```

gives me the following error:

> AttributeError: '_QueryIterator' object has no attribute 'order'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example given in the docs shows that `.order('name')` is attached to a query.

In your example you are attaching it after the query has been run.

Try:

```
q = Institution_Table.all().order('name')
results = q.run()
```

Here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Restrictions_on_Queries

Comment: Or if you want it all on one line:

    q = Institution_Table.all()..order('name').run(batch_size=2000)